# Is it possible to separately manage TFS branches' backlog items for a project?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I have two separate branches created for a project with two users - each user only has access to their branch.

I have created the project backlog items, however each user when logged into Visual Studio Online can see the backlog items - which is ok.  However once one user completes an item in their branch, I don't want that item to affect the other user's ability to continue working on that item.

I want to test how each developer creates a new UI on their respective branches.  Essentially the work is the same, but the way they implement would be different.

For example, an item may be "Update website front page".

Essentially I want them both to do the same thing but on their own branch.  Can we separate backlog items by branch?

Comment: Can you explain this scenario in more detail? Why are you doing the same work on two branches?

Comment: I want to see how each developer implements the requirements.

Comment: But why are you implementing the same requirements twice?

Comment: It's the same requirement, I.E. "new UI for homepage", but on each branch.  I could do this with two separate projects.  Maybe this is the wrong way of going about it.  Other suggestions?

Comment: So why not implement the requirement in one branch and then merge the change to the other branch? That's what I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have some crazy Hunger Games development scenario going on and as Daniel said, better to develop in one branch and merge to the other.

However, if you want to restrict Work Items across Teams or TFS Groups then you can restrict the Area Path.  So, either set up a team for each developer or simply create an Area Path for each branch and set security on it.

Have a look at [Customize area and iteration paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Work/customize/modify-areas-iterations) and the section on "Set permissions to restrict access to work items"

[image: Set Security on Area Path]